# Bash - Convert sub.site.com in to com_site_sub?

Tags: bash

I am writing a script that will do some automated things, and it requires to be put in the format `<tld>_<site>_<sub>` for now.

I will basically provoke it as such: ./add.sh about.site.com

Which will add the corresponding entries once the name is extracted

How could I write this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can mess with `$IFS` to change how things like `read` parse text:

```
hostname="foo.bar.com"
IFS=. read sub site tld <<< "$hostname"
echo ${tld}_${site}_${sub}
```

Comment: I do like it! and will use it in this situation. Next time I will actually use just PHP (very comfortable with it), I am only running this script 10-20 times a year or so, no need for speed battles. ~John.

Answer (score 1):

Or awk (a little cleaner than sed):

```
echo $1 | awk -F"." '{print $3 "_" $2 "_" $1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `sed`:

```
echo $1 | sed 's/\([^.]*\)\.\([^.]*\)\.\([^.]*\)/\3.\2.\1/'
```

Lots of backslashes, and it involves two processes, but it could have advantages if you need to handle many such substitutions in a single invocation of the script.